# Why won't lda() accept a string as it's 'formula' argument?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm doing some regression analysis and I've come across some strange behavior from the `lda` function in the `MASS` library. Specifically, it seems to be unable to accept a string as it's `formula` argument. This doesn't appear to be a problem for the base `glm` functions. I've constructed a small example using `iris` to illustrate the point.

```
library(MASS)
myForm<-"Species~Petal.Length"
# Disregard the warnings from this line, they're an artifact of the example. It works.
lgrIris<-glm(formula=myForm, data=iris, family="binomial")
# Breaks. 
ldaIris<-lda(formula=myForm, data=iris)
```

The final line above throws:

```
Error in lda.default(formula = myForm, data = iris) : 
argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Which, judging from the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/MASS/html/lda.html), seems to indicate that `lda` doesn't think it's been provided a `formula` argument. Does anyone know why this is happening, or how to fix it?

Comment: You can use `as.formula`: `lda(formula=as.formula(myForm), data=iris)`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I'm relatively new to R, and didn't know there was a native `formula` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn "myForm" into a formula using `as.formula()`:

```
myForm <- "Species~Petal.Length"
class(myForm)
# [1] "character"
myForm <- as.formula(myForm)
class(myForm)
# [1] "formula"
myForm
# Species ~ Petal.Length

lda(formula=myForm, data=iris)
# Call:
# lda(myForm, data = iris)

# Prior probabilities of groups:
#     setosa versicolor  virginica 
#  0.3333333  0.3333333  0.3333333 

# Group means:
#            Petal.Length
# setosa            1.462
# versicolor        4.260
# virginica         5.552

# Coefficients of linear discriminants:
#                   LD1
# Petal.Length 2.323774
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myForm<-as.formula(paste("Species","Petal.Length",sep="~"))
lgrIris<-glm(formula=myForm, data=iris, family="binomial")
```